# reorganize front-end files in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, frontend

My front end files are very messy, I wanted to reorganize them this way:

- separate .html.erb files into smaller components, actually as small
  as possible.
- Get rid of .scss files  .
- write .html.erb file like this:

  ```
  <body>
    # html and erb code here
  </body>

  <script>
    # javascript code here
  </script>

  <style scoped>
    # scss code here
  </style>
  ```

Is this a good idea ? Is there any risk of loosing speed of loading when users are on the app ?

Comment: you want to write `css`, `js` and `html` all in one page?

Comment: For most files, yes. Most of them would be actually small components, so It would not creates 'fat' front-end files

Comment: That seems very unusual. Not in a good way.

Comment: Yeah I know it is unusual, which is why I ask; What' song with this then ? Any disadvantage beyond the 'practical' side ?

Comment: its about opinion, there is no correct answer to it. people moved from all assets like `css`, `js` in one place to separating them out. having said that, I don't think you will notice significant difference in the load time if you really include all of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to how React and Angular organize CSS and JS, but they both have very good view encapsulation, unlike Rails.  You could use scopes like you suggest, however this still feels like a Rails anti-pattern to me.  In Rails, scripts and styles are supposed to go the `app/assets` folder by design.  If you are collaborating on this project or can anticipate needing to hand it off to another team at any point in the future, better go with the flow. I recently inherited a project with thousands of lines of inline styles and javascipt and it was a nightmare. Convention over configuration and all that.

Also keep in mind that **browsers do not cache inline styles and scripts**, so in the long run you are negatively impacting load time by not using linked files and allowing the browser to cache them.

Breaking up your long view files and templates into smaller partials and helpers is a good pattern in Rails.  As far as your stylesheets and javascripts go, I recommend keeping them in your `app/assets` folder.  You could use sprockets to include them, `require`s, `@include`s, etc.

Personally, I do something like this for a sort of psuedo-encapsulation:

```
<!-- In your layout file -->
<head>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <%= javascript_include_tag controller.controller_name, 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag controller.controller_name, media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <%= yield :end_of_head %>
</head>
```

That way you are minimizing load time and helping encapsulation by only loading the JS and CSS for that specific controller (don't forget to add to `config/assets.rb`) as well as any global CSS or JS.

For example, if I have a `UsersController` with some pages for viewing profiles, changing settings, signing up, etc, I would have an `app/assets/stylesheets/users.scss` and an `app/assets/javascripts/users.js` that is automatically loaded on those pages.  You could even take this a step further and have JS and CSS files specifically for each controller action.

In your partials and helpers, you can do this:

```
<%= content_for :end_of_head %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'partials/thing' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'partials/thing' %>
<% end %>
```

Just my $0.02

Also note, this approach is endorsed by the Rails core team: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the kind of feedback I was looking for. Indeed I think the fact that it isn't possible for browsers to cache inline stuff and scripts tags is a big disadvantage for this solution. I still don't really like how front end files are organised in Rails but this approach will still help me a lot for sure.